# Writing over current data pulling data from two source worksheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am building off my previous question to write a program that takes data from columns in two worksheets and transfers them to a destination worksheet. The second workbook's data (I plan to add more workbooks) is writing over the first. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import openpyxl
import calendar

# Open the destination workbook
dest_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Liquid Portfolio Attribution Analysis - Blank.xlsx')

# Define the destination sheet and the starting row
dest_sheet = dest_wb['Data']

def get_maximum_rows(*, sheet_object):
    rows = 0
    for max_row, row in enumerate(sheet_object, 1):
        if not all(col.value is None for col in row):
            rows += 1
    return rows

# Get the maximum row with data in the destination sheet
dest_last_row = get_maximum_rows(sheet_object=dest_sheet)

# Set the starting row for copying data in the destination sheet
dest_row = dest_last_row + 1

# Loop through each set of workbooks
for month in ['01']:
    for alpha in ['I', 'II']:
        # Open the source workbook
        wb_name = f'2022-{month} Alpha {alpha} - Workbook - MTester.xlsx'
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(wb_name, data_only=False)

        # Get the PCAP sheet
        sheet_name = f'2022-{month} PCAP (R)'
        sheet = wb[sheet_name]
        last_row = sheet.max_row

        # Copy the data and paste it into the destination sheet

        # Add the date to column B
        last_day = calendar.monthrange(2022, int(month))[1]
        date_str = f'{int(month)}/{last_day}/2022'
        dest_sheet[f'B{dest_row+1}'].value = date_str

        #Create dictionary with key value pairs to map source columns to destination columns
        data_map = {'A': 'C', 'B': 'E', 'D': 'F', 'F': 'G', 'H': 'H', 'U': 'J', 'AI': 'I', 'AO': 'K'}

        #Determines the last row to copy based on the max number of rows between the source and dest sheets
        last_row = sheet.max_row
        print(f"Source sheet last row: {sheet.max_row}")
        print(f"Destination row: {dest_row}")
        
        for row in range(6, last_row + 1):
            dest_row += 1
            print(f"Destination row: {dest_row}")
            source_row_data = [col.value for col in sheet[f'A{row}:AO{row}'][0]] #Creates a list of values for each column in the current row of source sheet
            if any(col_value is not None for col_value in source_row_data):
                for source_col, dest_col in data_map.items(): #Iterates through items in data_map dictionary
                    if len(source_col) == 1:
                        source_col_val = source_row_data[ord(source_col) - 65]  
                    else:
                        # Treat the column as a special case and manually convert it to the corresponding column number
                        col_num = (ord(source_col[0]) - 64) * 26 + (ord(source_col[1]) - 65)
                        source_col_val = source_row_data[col_num - 1]
                    dest_col_val = dest_sheet[f'{dest_col}{row}'] #Sets dest_col_val to the cell in the destination sheet corr. to current dest column being iterated over and current row
                    if source_col in ['H', 'U', 'AI'] and row == last_row:
                        dest_col_val.value = None
                    else:
                        dest_col_val.value = source_col_val
                #print(f"Source column length: {len(source_col)}")
            else:
                print(f'Row{row} has blank data')
                
    wb.close()

dest_wb.save('Liquid Portfolio Attribution Analysis - Copy - Tester Big.xlsx')
```

Here is my console:
'Source sheet last row: 11
Destination row: 4
Destination row: 5
Destination row: 6
Destination row: 7
Destination row: 8
Destination row: 9
Destination row: 10
Source sheet last row: 11
Destination row: 10
Destination row: 11
Destination row: 12
Destination row: 13
Destination row: 14
Destination row: 15
Destination row: 16'

[image: Source 1]

[image: Source 2]

[image: Destination]

Comment: It looks as though you are using 'row' as the row number variable on the source file and the same 'row' variable as the row number variable on the destination file. This may work for the first sheet where the source rows match the destination rows. However as you see on the second (and subsequent) the source row is going to start at 6 again and the destination you want to continue from the end of the last used row, otherwise it will just overwrite what the first file wrote in rows 6+.

Comment: I see. Is it as simple as modifying

 dest_col_val = dest_sheet[f'{dest_col}{dest_row}'] to 

dest_col_val = dest_sheet[f'{dest_col}{row}'] ?